# How do I set only the Parent ul to active and not ALL links to specific page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

Here is the script that sets active link.  As you can see from the image attached, when you click on contact, all the links that link to contact.aspx are set to active.  I know the loc.search(href) does this, however I only want to set the main menu link. ( i will use breadcrumbs for the other..)

```
   [Here is the site where this is happening][1]

 // =========  USAGE, put in MasterPage Header ======
    //  <script type="text/javascript">
    //     $(document).ready(function () {
    //         $('.menu').activeMenu();!
    //    });
    // </script>

(function ($) {
    $.fn.activeMenu = function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            idSwitch: 'current',
            defaultSite: null,
            defaultIndex: 0
        },
    intialize = function (id) {
        var op = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        var loc = location.href;
        var activeCount = 0;

 $(id).find('a').each(function () {  
            var href = $(this).attr('href');

   if (loc.search(href) != -1) {
        $(this).attr('id', op.idSwitch);   // ookie change this to this.parent.

 activeCount++;
            }
       else {
                $(this).attr('id', '');
          }

        if (activeCount == 0) {
            if (loc.search(op.defaultSite) != -1) {
                $(id).find('a').eq(0).attr('id', op.idSwitch);
            }
        }
 }); 

}

    return this.each(function () {
        intialize(this);
    });
}
)(jQuery);
```

aspx html code

```
 <ul class="menu" id="responsive">

        <li><a href="default.aspx" id="current"><i class="halflings white home"></i> Home</a></li>

        <li><a href="#"><i class="halflings white file"></i>Services</a>
            <!-- Mega Menu / Start -->
            <ul class="cols4">
                <li class="col4">
                    <p>Below is a list of our services for additional information <a href="contact.aspx">contact us</a> today!!</p>
                </li>
                <li class="col1">
                    <h5>Digital Signage</h5>
                    <ol>
                        <li><a href="about-us.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="flexslider.html">FlexSlider</a></li>
                        <li><a href="pricing-tables.html">Pricing Tables</a></li>
                        <li><a href="elements.html">Elements</a></li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <li class="col1">
                    <h5>Development</h5>
                    <ol>
                        <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ's</a></li>
                        <li><a href="404-page.html">404 Page</a></li>
                        <li><a href="left-sidebar.html">Left Sidebar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="right-sidebar.html">Right Sidebar</a></li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <li class="col1">
                    <h5>Consulting</h5>
                    <p>This <a href="#">Mega Menu</a> can handle everything. Lists, paragraphs, forms...</p>
                </li>
                <li class="col1">
                <ol>
                    <h5>Hosting</h5>
                    <p>Our <a href="hosting.aspx">hosting packages</a> start from your standard packages all the way to custom cloud solutions... <a href="hosting.aspx">click here</a>  to learn more</p>
                </ol>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Mega Menu / End -->
        </li>


<li><a href="#"><i class="halflings white cog"></i> Shortcodes</a>
        <!-- Second Level / Start -->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="elements.html">Elements</a></li>
            <li><a href="icons.html">Icons</a></li>
            <li><a href="pricing-tables.html">Pricing Tables</a></li>
            <li><a href="typography.html">Typography</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Second Level / End -->
    </li>

<li><a href="#"><i class="halflings white briefcase"></i> Portfolio</a>
    <!-- Second Level / Start -->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="portfolio-2.html">2 Columns</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio-3.html">3 Columns</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio-4.html">4 Columns</a></li>
        <li><a href="single-project.html">Single Project</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Second Level / End -->
</li>

<li><a href="#"><i class="halflings white shopping-cart"></i> Shop</a>
    <!-- Second Level / Start -->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="product-page.html">Product Page</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Second Level / End -->
</li>

<li><a href="about.aspx"><i class="halflings white user"></i> About</a>
    <!-- Second Level / Start -->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="blog-large-image.html">Large Image</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog-medium-image.html">Medium Image</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog-post.html">Single Post</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Second Level / End -->
</li>

<li><a href="contact.aspx"><i class="halflings white envelope"></i>Contact</a></li>
```

Comment: What image? You didn't attach anything as far as I can tell.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0cnqc2wj/1/ I'm not sure what you're talkinga bout. When I run this code through jsfiddle, it works fine. It only actives the "About" within the `.menu` and not within the body content.

Comment: if you look at w3.ookie.com, if you select an item under services, that item gets highlighted but not "Services" the parent item. I would like to have Services highlighted and have the child one's only bolded.